# "Fixing" a HTML file in google sheets?

Tags: html, google-sheets

I have an excel file (.xls so it's older) that when I import and read into google sheets that gives me a lot of data (see below) in cells of a sheet. Is there a way to go through the file and remove the HTML formatting?

```
<div class="reportHeader">
Monday
&ndash;
Sunday
</div>

<br />

</form>

<div class="allResults">

<div class="staffHeader">
<span class="staffName">
Beal
</span>
```

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **Search using regular expressions** option in **Edit > Find and replace** to replace text strings that start with `<` and end with `>` with an empty value, using a pattern like this:

`<.+?>`

Comment: Thanks!, that makes a lot of sense thinking about it now. Another issue I have is that when I imported the file it went from a table( i.e 5rows x 10 columns) to a single column (i.e 50 rows, 1 column). Is there a way to fix this issue within GAS?

Comment: Yes, but that is a different question. Please post it separately.